# Is there a way to get an Ultra Minimal YouTube player for web?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I want a YouTube player that just has play, pause, and close as options. Maybe full screen would be fine. No recommended videos, more videos, etc.

I want to share YouTube videos through Google Classroom. I don't want them to be able to click any link that re-directs them back to the YouTube watch page.

Google Classroom only allows you to search for videos using its interface OR provide a watch link / url. I'm trying to use a workaround using an embed code on a Google Site. If it's easy enough to do I might try to teach teachers how to create their own links. Or maybe I can make a custom embed code generator that I can share with them.

I've looked at YouTube embed API code, but cannot get anything to work. I assume it's just my small amount of knowledge about how to code it.

I know I want `controls=0` `modestbranding=1` and `showinfo=0` at the least

I expected this to strip out the navigation bar, YouTube watermark, and Video Title. It didn't do any of them. When I remove all but one of the variables it does that variable. Again, apologies about my lack of understanding on the topic.

Comment: I used to also use `&rel=0` in the embed URL to remove  the 'related videos' being displayed at the end, but Google disabled that too. So I don't think you're going to get what you're looking for very easily.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Unfortunately I believe you are all correct. 

There doesn't seem to be any way to make it as stripped down as I need.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not going to be possible to make it that minimalist.  All of the options for embedding videos are listed here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

You could use an online tool like this to customize everything that's available with an easier to use UI:

https://www.classynemesis.com/projects/ytembed/

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to be possible to remove the watermark or redirects to Youtube. 
All options for the iFrame API are [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say, but I don't think you are able to do so without breaking the YouTube Terms of Service. Removing their watermark sounds especially problematic.

> **General Use of the Service—Permissions and Restrictions**
>
> A. You agree not to distribute in any medium any part of the Service or the Content without YouTube's prior written authorization, unless YouTube makes available the means for such distribution through functionality offered by the Service (such as the Embeddable Player).
>
> B. You agree not to alter or modify any part of the Service.