# how to remove more video's remove youtube embeded code

Tags: youtube, embedded-resource, youtube-iframe-api

How to remove **more video's** from youtube embedded code.
I have checked the below YouTube embed code. **but it's showing more video's**.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0yrBllVqQFE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;autoplay=1;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I had checked the **"ytp-pause-overlay=0"** property. so the code becomes like below. but it's not working. it's showing the "more video's".

```
<iframe width="100%" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0yrBllVqQFE?rel=0&amp;ytp-pause-overlay=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0;autoplay=1;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Please help me any latest embedded code for resolving the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, it seems this is not possible: See `https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887769/4092887`.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube embed showinfo has been ignored since September 25, 2018 and there is no suggestion of a workaround or a new parameter that you could send to archive the old results. They have removed it. If you tried to force it out using javascript and css i would almost suggest you are against the TOC which states your not allowed to change that display. People should know you are showing something from YouTube.

So you can try [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com) or self hosted video solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Credits to the **[linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258456/4092887)** and the tool called "[classynemesis](https://www.classynemesis.com/projects/ytembed/)".

Thanks to **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258456/4092887)** and using the [tool called "classynemesis"](https://www.classynemesis.com/projects/ytembed/) linked in the same answer, I was able to set the parameters for your video, removing the "related" videos.

This is the URL of your video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/0yrBllVqQFE?modestbranding=1&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&fs=0&disablekb=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1
```

N.B If even with these modifications you can't get the results you desire, it might be that these changes aren't possible *(according with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887769/4092887))*.